# How can I report an error if the existing dictionary sees another item in python with the same key but different value

Tags: python

Firstly, Suppose I have a dictionary like given below:

```
temp = {'A': 3, 'S': 1}
```

Now if I encounter an item like `'A': 4` will it be added to the dictionary something like:

```
temp = {'A': 4, 'S': 1}
```

leaving behind the previously value of key `A` which was `3`

Secondly, if my dictionary is

```
{'A': 3, 'S': 1}
```

How can I report an error if the dictionary sees another item like `'A': 4` or `'S': 5`

Comment: So you are trying to merge dictb in to dicta and warn when the value in dictb will change an existing value in dicta?  Or you are running through a set of data that may have duplicate keys and you want to warn when a given key has already been encountered?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Any context for this question?

Comment: what if I have to report that the key which is just seen is having a different value from the one already in the dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

You can test to see if a key already exists in a dictionary:

```
if 'A' in temp:
    # report the error
```

For merging two dictionaries you can test to see if the keys overlap by creating sets out of them and ensuring the intersection is empty:

```
if set(temp.keys()).intersection(set(other.keys())):
    # report the error
```

If it's OK to have a duplicate key as long as it's the same value, a simple change to the above will give it to you:

```
if 'A' in temp and temp['A'] != 4:
    # can't insert the new value 'A': 4

if [True for x in set(temp.keys()).intersection(set(other.keys())) if temp[x] != other[x]]:
    # at least one value in temp doesn't match a value in other
```

Comment: after all, it is possible to subclass from dict, replacing whatever method is responsible for insertion with some modified logic

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like this?

```
temp = {
  'A': 3
  'S' : 1
}

def insert_or_raise(k, v) {
   global temp # assuming temp is global and accessible
   val = temp.get(k, None)
   if not val:
       temp[k] = v
       return
   if v != val:
       raise Error("values are not same , already inserted %s for key %s " % (val, k)) 

}

insert('B', 1) # inserts okay
insert('B', 1) # does nothing, same key, value pair exists
insert('B', 2) # raise Error value is not 1 for key B
```

Comment: I would not use `if not v:` - `0` is a perfectly good value, and will break this code... (as well any valid object that happens to be non-true)

Comment: changed it to val, it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

```
def strictInsert( existingDict, key, value ):
    # check to see if the key is present
    if key in existingDict:
        # assuming you only want an error if the new value is 
        # different from the old one...
        if existingDict[key] != value:
            # raise an error
            raise ValueError( "Key '%s' already in dict"%key )
    else:
        # insert into the dict
        existingDict[key] = value


temp = {'A': 3, 'S': 1} 

strictInsert( temp, 'A', 4 )
```

This yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 15, in <module>
    strictInsert( temp, 'A', 4 )
  File "so.py", line 8, in strictInsert
    raise ValueError( "Key '%s' already in dict"%key )
ValueError: Key 'A' already in dict
```

Comment: Wouldn't `KeyError` be more appropriate than `ValueError`?

Comment: I wasn't particularly happy with either `KeyError` or `ValueError`, but you could make the case for `KeyError`. The official description says "raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys", which is in a way the opposite of the actual problem. `LookupError` has a more general definition: "base class for the exceptions that are raised when a key or index used on a mapping or sequence is invalid", so that might be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is probably to subclass `dict` and override `__setitem__()` to raise an exception when the key already exists.  Unless someone knows of a pre-existing write-once dictionary in `collections` or something...

```
class WriteOnceDict(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            retrieved_value = self[key]
        except KeyError:
            super(WriteOnceDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        if retrieved_value != value:
            raise KeyError('Different value already added for %s.' % key)

mydict = WriteOnceDict()
for key, value in input_data: #or appropriate code for whatever your input data is
    mydict[key] = value
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, should be upvoted more